# HDFS disk usage

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

How to display Non dfs used % ?

If i use `hdfs dfsadmin -report` command it display like this

> Name: 10.87.88.145:50010 (aline.node5.cdc)
>
> ```
> Hostname: aline.node5.cdc
>
> Decommission Status: Normal
>
> Configured Capacity: 46953267200 (43.73 GB)
>
> DFS Used: 13463552 (12.84 MB)
>
> Non DFS Used: 30785171456 (28.67 GB)
>
> DFS Remaining: 16154632192 (15.05 GB)
>
> DFS Used%: 0.03%
>
> DFS Remaining%: 34.41%
>
> Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
>
> Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
>
> Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
>
> Cache Used%: 100.00%
>
> Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
>
> Xceivers: 2
>
> Last contact: Thu Jun 21 01:02:55 EDT 2018
> ```

But I want non-dfs used percentage? Is there any specific command for it.

Comment: Try running 'hdfs dfs -du /' command

Comment: You could parse the output and do that math, but why do you care about non dfs?